# Two Different Datepickers in the same page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I have problem displaying two Datepickers on the same page. The one should be displayed with a hidden body like this

[image]

and the other one should be a regular datepicker.

To achieve the first functionality I do this:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy'
});
```

And then by using css i hide the body:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

But when I want to display the second datepicker I cannot overwrite that css style.

I tried

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css('display', '');
```

I tried even completely removing the style attribute but still with no luck.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').removeAttr('style');
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSudq/1/) of what i have right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally reached an acceptable solution using this code:

```
            $('#startDate').focusin(function() {
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
            });
            $('#startDate').focusout(function() {
                $('.date-picker').datepicker('close');
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').show();
            });
```

and completely removing the css.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSudq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

can you try

In JS
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').show();

In CSS

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I have two fields.May be it help u:-

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.